# Python improve use of dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I've written the following module, it works.  But I believe it can be improved.

I start by first importing a JSON file into both labelled_data and dictionary_revised.  I then go through and calculate word similarity score and store that percentage within labelled_data['SimilarityScore'].  Then, I use the module below to further narrow the labelled_data into smaller dataset, which I then append to dictionary_revised and save.

However, when I look at the following module, it just doesn't seem like the best use of dataframes.  Any suggestions to improve?

In addition, it is better to use 'lambda' or use the 'for index,...' method? To me, the lambda way means that I iterate through the dataframe multiple times in order to calculate the different percentages.

Thanks for the assistance.

```
#95%
series95Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.95 else False, axis=1)
numOf95Rows = len(series95Obj[series95Obj == True].index)

#85% 
series85Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if (x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.85 and x['SimilarityScore'] < 0.95) else False, axis=1)
numOf85Rows = len(series85Obj[series85Obj == True].index)

#75%
series75Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if (x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.75 and x['SimilarityScore'] < 0.85) else False, axis=1)
numOf75Rows = len(series75Obj[series75Obj == True].index)

#below 75%  
numOfLess75Rows = intTotalEvaluated - (numOf95Rows + numOf85Rows + numOf75Rows)
```

Count number by row:

```
for index, row in labelled_data.iterrows():
    if 0.95 <= row['SimilarityScore'] < 1.00:
        numOf95Rows += 1
    elif 0.85 <= row['SimilarityScore'] < 0.95:
        numOf85Rows += 1
    elif 0.75 <= row['SimilarityScore'] < 0.85:
        numOf75Rows += 1
    elif row['SimilarityScore'] < 0.75:
        numOfLess75Rows += 1
    else:
        pass
```

Full module:

```
 #Export source labelled data and export as JSON
  def update_dictionary(labelled_data, dictionary_revised, evaluationScore = 0.75, updateDictionaryScore = 0.75):

now = datetime.datetime.now()
currentDate = now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
dFile = 'Dictionary_' +  currentDate + '.json'
aFile = 'Analysis_Output_' + currentDate + '.xlsx'

#set min similarity score for output
score = labelled_data['SimilarityScore'] > evaluationScore

#dataframe used for calculating overall percentages
s1 = labelled_data[score]

#dataframe used for final dictionary update
scoreFinal = s1['SimilarityScore'] >= updateDictionaryScore
s2 = s1[scoreFinal]

#total evaluated
intTotalEvaluated = labelled_data.shape[0]   

#95%
series95Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.95 else False, axis=1)
numOf95Rows = len(series95Obj[series95Obj == True].index)

#85% 
series85Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if (x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.85 and x['SimilarityScore'] < 0.95) else False, axis=1)
numOf85Rows = len(series85Obj[series85Obj == True].index)

#75%
series75Obj = s1.apply(lambda x: True if (x['SimilarityScore'] >= 0.75 and x['SimilarityScore'] < 0.85) else False, axis=1)
numOf75Rows = len(series75Obj[series75Obj == True].index)

#below 75%  
numOfLess75Rows = intTotalEvaluated - (numOf95Rows + numOf85Rows + numOf75Rows)

#drop columns
del s2['QueryText']
del s2['DateAdded']

#rename and rearrange columns
s2.rename(columns={'SimilarText': 'QueryText'}, inplace=True)
s2.rename(columns={'Subjectmatter': 'Category'}, inplace=True)
s3 = s2.reindex(columns=['QueryText', 'Category','SimilarityScore'])
s3['DateAdded'] = currentDate

#calculate the number of net new rows being added to the dictionary
intNetNewAdded = s3.shape[0]

#append results
results = dictionary_revised.append(s3, ignore_index=True)
#save to JSON file
results.to_json(dFile, orient='records')

return 1,currentDate, dFile, aFile, intTotalEvaluated, numOf95Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf75Rows, numOfLess75Rows, intNetNewAdded
```

Here is a small sample of the initial dictionary:

```
[
  {
    "QueryText": "store",
    "Subjectmatter": "Shopping"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "travel",
    "Subjectmatter": "Travel & Vacation"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "paycheck",
    "Subjectmatter": "HR"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "holidays",
    "Subjectmatter": "Travel & Vacation"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "benefits",
    "Subjectmatter": "HR & Benefits"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "library",
    "Subjectmatter": "Information"
  }
  {
    "QueryText": "store",
    "Subjectmatter": "Shopping"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "expense",
    "Subjectmatter": "Finance"
  },
  {
    "QueryText": "jobs",
    "Subjectmatter": "Career & Jobs"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of what one of your DataFrames looks like?  That would be as helpful as seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. For counting numbers by row you may replace your loop by this optimized code in Pandas:

```
df_numOf95Rows = labelled_data[(labelled_data['SimilarityScore']>=0.95) & (labelled_data['SimilarityScore']<1.0)]
numOf95Rows = df_numOf95Rows.shape[0]
```

You may apply the same for `numOf75Rows`, `numOf85Rows`, `numOfLess75Rows`.

2. For the last part of your code where you use conditions in order to fill with `True` or `False`, you may use the function `where()` of `Series`. You may find more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html). Generally speaking, the `apply` function is very slow, try to avoid it if possible.